# Where I can I find a public URL that returns a dataset of approx 3000 rows in JSON format for testing

Tags: jsbin

I need to put together a jsBin example that demonstrates a problem I'm having with some UI controls, which doesn't manifest itself with a only a few records. I need a dataset of about 3000-5000 rows in JSON format that can be obtained via a URL by an AJAX XHR call. Can someone suggest a website with possibly government or open-source data that can be used for such testing?

P.S. It can't just be a download of a zipped file that can be expanded into a JSON text file. I need a JSON XHR response.

P.P.S.  Ideally it would have 50-75 distinct values in one of the columns so I could demonstrate a grouping/aggregation issue.  Data by US State or by Zipccode within a state would be excellent.

P.P.P.S. I've been searching the internet and found this site, now trying to figure out how to get JSON instead of XML:

http://www.sba.gov/about-sba-services/7617#city-county-state

All you have to do is this:

http://www.sba.gov/about-sba-services/7617#city-county-state/NY.json

Comment: Many website like Yelp (api.yelp.com- simple step you need to register your self), Bing etc. provides JSON as response, you can give it a try maybe it can help. I have recently worked on Yelp and it can definitely help.

Comment: @spike read question, not answer. There are 3 links there.

Comment: @David Jashi: the data provided by the first answer is not in json format and the second requires a bunch of loops; I need to point the control at a URL.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a lot of open data here

[free open data](https://nycopendata.socrata.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/query) there should be a query to get you that many rows and they offer json responses.

EDIT: Theres a similiar site [DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/About) I built this query which will return JSON and has about 3k rows:

http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+distinct+%3FConcept+where+%7B%5B%5D+a+%3FConcept%7D+LIMIT+3000&format=json%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on

you can go [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) and customize the query if you need more data.

-Ken

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a page with a LOOP that generate those records as you desire. Shouldn't be so hard.

Maybe a Java Servlet.